# How to execute a SPARQL update in SailGraph by Tinkerpop

Tags: neo4j, rdf, sparql, owl, tinkerpop

My question is basically how to properly execute a SPARQL update using SailGraph created by Tinkerpop.

```
DELETE { ?i_id_iri rdfs:label "BII-I-1" }
INSERT { ?i_id_iri rdfs:label "BII-I-4" }
WHERE
  { 
    ?investigation rdf:type obi:0000011.
    ?i_id_iri rdf:type iao:0000577.
    ?i_id_iri iao:0000219 ?investigation.
  }
```

I have this query so far with the prefixes added on top from another file but it does not work.
The code i run is as follows

```
query = parser.parseUpdate(queryString, baseURI);
UpdateExpr expr = query.getUpdateExprs().get(0);
Dataset dataset = query.getDatasetMapping().get(expr);
GraphDatabase.getSailConnection().executeUpdate(expr, dataset, new EmptyBindingSet(), false);
```

Comment: In what sense does it not work?  Error, data not modified as expected, something else?

Comment: The query is executed successfully but when i try to retrieve using the old id that should have been replaced its still there

Comment: The underlying database is Neo4J and sail graph is initialised from that

Comment: Do you have a small testcase showing this, so I can test locally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with the Tinkerpop GraphSail, but assuming it implements the Sesame SAIL API correctly, executing a SPARQL query is far easier if you just wrap it in a `SailRepository`, like so:

```
 TinkerGraph graph = new TinkerGraph();
 Sail sail = new GraphSail(graph);    

 Repository rep = new SailRepository(sail);
 rep.initialize();
```

You can then use Sesame's [Repository API](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#The_Repository_API), which is far more user-friendly than trying to do operations directly on the SAIL (which is not designed for that purpose).

To open a connection and execute a SPARQL update, for example, you do:

```
RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection();
try {
      String sparql = "INSERT {?s a <foo:example> . } WHERE {?s ?p ?o } ";

      Update update = conn.prepareUpdate(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, sparql);
      update.execute();
}
finally {
  conn.close();
}
```

See link above for more details on Sesame's Repository API, or check out the [Javadoc](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/package-summary.html).